# How to tell which comment was flagged?

Tags: discussion, support

I've been trying to learn how to utilize flags more effectively. In doing so, I've been going over my past flags, both on answers, and comments, to determine which flags were disputed or declined, and why. Going back to some of my previous declined comment flags, I've been unable to determine which comment I flagged (Which is probably a good thing, as it means I've learned more about what kind of comments are acceptable). Is there any way I can more directly determine which comment I flagged?

Comment: If the comment was deleted outside the moderation process, I think it shows your flag as declined sometimes.